# Event called in UIViewController when return from a dialog?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, onresume

Does an event exist in `UIViewController` called when you return from a dialog?

I'm asking for notification permission doing this:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
```

I need to override an event in `UIViewController` to do some stuff when that dialog is not present anymore, so when the screen has recovered the focus. **That is exactly the behaviour `onResume` does in Android.**

I tried with this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onResume), name:
        UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
@objc func onResume() {

}
```

and with this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {}
```

None of these functions are called when the dialog is closed.

Comment: `requestAuthorization` has an optional completion handler parameter: `center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { success, error in }`.

Comment: @PylypDukhov thank you, but, does UIViewController  have something similar to onResume for doing this?

Comment: Ah, you're using async version, then when `requestAuthorization` finishes performing, means that alert disappeared. No, in iOS lifecycle view controller doesn't disappear when it presents an alert (after all you still can see it underneath), that's why your attempts doesn't work. There's no other way except using information from `requestAuthorization`, in async way or with completion.

Comment: @PylypDukhov I have the logic I need to do in the UIViewController of the current screen. Is there a way to call a method on the UIViewController of the current screen when the requestAuthorization dialog has been closed?

Comment: It depends on your architecture. The most unsafe way, available in any circumstances, is to send your own notification to notification center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can know that alert disappeared, is from completion handlers. In this case:

```
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { success, error in
    // alert disappeared
}
```

Or async version:

```
do {
    let success = try await center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
} catch {
}
// alert disappeared
```